# Unity GUI Label Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have 2 GUI Labels in a C# Script. I would like to position one of them at 40% of the screen, and the other at 60% of the screen.

```
GUI.Label (new Rect (340, 20, 100, 100), ""+ var);
GUI.Label (new Rect (410, 20, 100, 100), ""+ var1);
```

Are there any options to choose from to be more accurate instead of '340' and '410'?

Comment: (int)(Screen.height * 0.4)

Credits to: PearsonArtPhoto

Comment: Cheers @PearsonArtPhoto - For next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always manually compute the location, as below.

```
(int)(Screen.height * 0.4)
```

Comment: PearsonArtPhoto 's answer worked fine.

"Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score"... I would have :) - Your answer was much appreciated.